# How to calculate the evaluation metrics (i.e., F1 score) in leave one subject out cv when a subject belongs to single class only

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, scikit-learn, f1score

I have dataset of 10 subjects. the  dataset has 4 classess. 0,1,2 and 3. The distribution of  classes are not same. For example subject 1 does not have 1,2 and 3. It belongs to zeros class. currently I am evaluating the model using leave one subject out.In such scenario how to calculate the evaluation metrics like F1 score. I  tried the sklearn classification report but for  some subjects there are  only one class. shall I consider the macro F1 score?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use summary statistics if you only have 10 data points. With that few datapoints, the summary statistics estimates will not be robust.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. actually, there  are  10 subjects. Each subject includes few thousands images. Therefore the  total samples are around 16000 images. but the problem is  some subjects does  not have all the classess (i.e., for subject one there are 2000 images all belongs to 0 class) in such cases how to measure evaluation  metrics.